# More details for "An error has occurred." message on Acumatica REST API?

Tags: acumatica

The new Acumatica REST api returns `{"message":"An error has occurred."}` whenever there's an error. Is there any way to get more details, like the way SOAP/Web Services returns the full stack trace?

Acumatica version: 6.10.0010

Comment: what version of Acumatica?

Comment: Are you doing your calls from the same machine as the one hosting the Acumatica instance?

Comment: Separate server. Version 6.10.0010.

Comment: if you access the login page of Acumatica - the full version is available in the bottom right.

Answer (score 1):

Currently detailed error message are only available when making calls from the same machine.

Just wanted to add a fix has been created and will be release as of the next version for 6.10 which is planned to come out on the 22 of February.

Comment: I was curious to this answer... ran a quick test and can confirm that I only received error details when making calls from the same machine. My remote machine didn't return anything beyond "An error has occurred". This appears to have worked for me in both 6.0 and 6.1. This should be marked as the answer.

Comment: So if an error happens in production there's no way to know what went wrong?

Comment: Yes for now this is the case.
You can always try to log the call that encountered the error so that you an run it from the same machine to have more details.